# Creating new relationships in Core Data migration

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

In my current Core Data model, I have a relationship called `workers` from `Company` to  `Person` entities. In the new version, I will have a new entity called `Department` related to  `Company` with `dept`, and the old relationship `workers` now from `Department` to `Person`.

In other words, in ver. 1:

`Company <--1--(workers)--n--> Person`

and in ver. 2:

```
Company <--1--(dept)--n--> Department
Department <--1--(workers)--n--> Person
```

I am using a custom `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` for `Company`'s migration, and create a `Department` in the `createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance` method. But how do I get the company's `workers` here, which may not have been created, and then set them to the new department's workers?